# orden en la ejecución

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes
Tengo un código en JavaScript en el que:
1. muestro una imagen
2.oculto un input
3 abro una ventana mediante alert()
Al ejecutarlo, primero me muestra el alert, luego continua una instrucción más de código y por último muestra la imagen y oculta el input

¿Por qué?

```
function dibujarMuerto()
{document.getElementById("horca").style.visibility="visible";
  for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
   {document.getElementById("error"+i).style.visibility="visible";}
     document.getElementById("miLetra").style.visibility="hidden";
     alert("Demasiado tiempo.Estás muerto");
}


function limpiar()
{document.getElementById("miLetra").value="";}

function comprobar()
{letra=document.getElementById("miLetra").value;

 pos1=palabra.indexOf(letra);
 pos2=palabra.lastIndexOf(letra);

 var esta=posibles.indexOf(letra);
 var nuevafecha=new Date();
   var horaFinal=nuevafecha.getHours();horaFinal=horaFinal*60;
   var minutosFinal=nuevafecha.getMinutes();
   var minutoss=horaFinal+minutosFinal;
   if((minutoss-minutos1)>-1)
    {dibujarMuerto();
     }

 if(esta==-1){

   if(pos1!=-1){alert("La letra está");          
     {if(pos1==pos2){ document.getElementById("cuadro"+pos1).innerHTML=letra;aciertos++;}               
      else{document.getElementById("cuadro"+pos1).innerHTML=letra;aciertos++;
         if(pos2!=-1){document.getElementById("cuadro"+pos2).innerHTML=letra;aciertos++;}
          }
     }
   } 
   else{alert("La letra NO está");error++;
      for(var i=0;i<error;i++)
        {document.getElementById("error"+i).style.visibility="visible";}
       }
   if(error>=6){alert("Estás muerto");}
   if(aciertos==palabra.length){alert("Has ganado");}
   posibles.push(letra);
}   
  else{alert("Esa letra ya la has dicho");}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque los cambios realizados en el DOM no se visualizan hasta haber acabado el bloque de ejecución de javascript.

Si quieres que el alert se muestre después de visualizarse las modificaciones del DOM puedes utilizar un setTimeout para que se ejecute en un bloque de ejecución diferente:

```
 document.getElementById("error"+i).style.visibility="visible";}
 document.getElementById("miLetra").style.visibility="hidden";
 setTimeout(function() {alert("Demasiado tiempo.Estás muerto");});
```

Pero ten en cuenta que si tienes código que se ejecuta a continuación éste se ejecutará también antes que el alert.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes toda la razón

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tener 3 variables booleanas, por ejemplo:

```
var tareaUno = false, tareaDos =  false, tareaTres = false;
```

tendrías que poner una variable en cada función  y cambiar el valor a true cada vez que se termine una tarea, si quieres que se muestre la alerta hasta que se hayan ejecutado los primeros pasos deberías preguntar si las 3 banderas están en true, en caso no ser así debes ejecutar las funciones que aún no tienen la bandera en true, es una manera un poco arcaica, espero me haya dado entender.